# getColumnLabel vs. getColumnName

Tags: java, resultset

What is the difference between [ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-) and  [ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName-int-)?

Label: Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and displays.

Name: Get the designated column's name.

Does anyone know how Label is determined?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
String getColumnLabel(int column) throws SQLException;
```

If a SQL `AS` is not specified, the value returned from 
          `getColumnLabel` will be the same as the value returned by the 
          `getColumnName` method.

Example:

```
select id as user_no from users
```

- getColumnLabel would return 'user_no'
- getColumnName would return 'id'

Comment: I am getting user_no for getColumnLabel  as well as getColumnName

Comment: @AjmalKhan Same here, at least with the MySQL driver

Comment: I am getting same name in both , using DB2 JCC driver as well. Any idea please  ?

Comment: getColumnName does not return what you say, not sure why.