# Is the 'as' keyword required in Oracle to define an alias?

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, required

Is the 'AS' keyword required in Oracle to define an alias name for a column in a SELECT statement?

I noticed that

```
SELECT column_name AS "alias"
```

is the same as

```
SELECT column_name "alias"
```

I am wondering what the consequences are of defining a column alias in the latter way.

Comment: Note that double quotes for the alias-name are required (as opposed to single quotes).  A small, but important, point.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to the select_list [Oracle select documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) the AS is optional.

As a personal note I think it is easier to read with the AS

Comment: in joined table alias, `AS` is not supported (tested on Oracle 11c)

Answer (score 35):

*(Tested on `Oracle 11g`)*

**About `AS`:**

- When used on **result column**, `AS` is optional.
- When used on **table name**, `AS` shouldn't be added, otherwise it's an error.

**About `double quote`:**

- It's optional & valid for both result column & table name.

**e.g**

```
-- 'AS' is optional for result column
select (1+1) as result from dual;
select (1+1) result from dual;


-- 'AS' shouldn't be used for table name
select 'hi' from dual d;


-- Adding double quotes for alias name is optional, but valid for both result column & table name,
select (1+1) as "result" from dual;
select (1+1) "result" from dual;

select 'hi' from dual "d";
```

Comment: Do you know of any reason why Oracle disallows `AS` with a table name? I'm curious as to why this is, as it seems rather inconsistent intuition-wise, and other DBMS such as MySQL allow it.

Comment: @ZeroKnight No idea, maybe due to history reason.

Answer (score 10):

### AS without double quotations is good.

```
SELECT employee_id,department_id AS department
FROM employees
order by department
```

### --ok--

```
SELECT employee_id,department_id AS "department"
FROM employees
order by department
```

--error on oracle--

so better to use AS without double quotation if you use ORDER BY clause

Comment: You can use an ORDER BY with a double quotation alias. This is especially helpfully if you have a space in the column name. So if your alias was `department_id AS "Department Name"` you would need to do `ORDER BY "Department Name"`.

Answer (score 7):

Both are correct. Oracle allows the use of both.

Answer (score 7):

My conclusion is that（Tested on 12c）:

- AS is always optional, either with or without ""; **AS makes no difference** (column alias only, you can not use AS preceding table alias)
- However, with or without "" does make difference because **"" lets lower case possible for an alias**

thus :

```
SELECT {T / t} FROM (SELECT 1 AS T FROM DUAL); -- Correct
SELECT "tEST" FROM (SELECT 1 AS "tEST" FROM DUAL); -- Correct
SELECT {"TEST" / tEST} FROM (SELECT 1 AS "tEST" FROM DUAL ); -- Incorrect

SELECT test_value AS "doggy" FROM test ORDER BY "doggy"; --Correct
SELECT test_value AS "doggy" FROM test WHERE "doggy" IS NOT NULL; --You can not do this, column alias not supported in WHERE & HAVING
SELECT * FROM test "doggy" WHERE "doggy".test_value IS NOT NULL; -- Do not use AS preceding table alias
```

---

So, the reason why USING AS AND "" causes problem is NOT AS

**Note:** "" double quotes are required if alias contains space OR if it contains lower-case characters and MUST show-up in Result set as lower-case chars. In all other scenarios its OPTIONAL and can be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

The quotes are required when we have a space in Alias Name like

```
SELECT employee_id,department_id AS "Department ID"
FROM employees
order by department
```

Comment: This should have been a comment

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between both, `AS` is just a more explicit way of mentioning the alias which is good because some dependent *libraries* depends on this small keyword. e.g. **JDBC 4.0**. Depend on use of it, different behaviour can be observed.

See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271250/814304). I would always suggest to use the full form of semantic to avoid such issues.