# Error executing SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some knowledge about SQL but a complete novice in Oracle. The following sql statement will execute properly in SQL Server. But this doesn't execute in Oracle and throws an error.

```
select Field1, * from Table1 where SomeField = 0
```

Please let know how to execute a similar statement in Oracle. The error recieved is as follows:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Comment: I deleted my answer almost immed. because I noticed I made an error-missed an alias. It happens sometimes when you rush... I do not know why you was able to see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
select Field1, a.* from Table1 a where SomeField = 0;
```

Comment: You can also use the table name as prefix, no need to alias.

Comment: For better readability, it is desirable to make table aliases with an AS key word, for example: Table1 AS a.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That will work too. Many different ways of tacking the same problem.

Comment: I agree, just to mention :) I prefer "AS" because my editor recognize key words, and color them, nothing more.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451195/is-the-as-keyword-required-in-oracle-to-define-an-alias

Comment: @veljasije you're confusing column aliasing with table aliasing. Table aliasing does not permit "AS" keyword in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try:

```
select Field1, Table1.* from Table1 where SomeField = 0
```