# What is wrong with my oracle select query below?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

[image]

Why my first select query shows error at 'AS' when the second one is ok?
- oracle sql
- error message: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: if you just remove the bracket from the first query it may work.

Comment: @bhavesh27, I've tried, it doesn't. Still 'SQL command not properly ended' error message pop up

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, sorry..noted on that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451195/is-the-as-keyword-required-in-oracle-to-define-an-alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not allow `as` in table level alias. It's allowed for column and subquery, that's why you don't get the error for the second example.

Fix it by removing `as` like below:

```
select * from cisa xxxx
```

Comment: Then why the second one is ok?

Comment: @Shahril that is subquery alias

Comment: how can I use alias for the first query, coz I need it..

Comment: @Shahril - this answer shows you how to alias a table - you literally just omit the `as` keyword.