# Possible correlation subqueries

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I'm new to subqueries and correlation is now trying to understand a problem.

I have a query:

```
SELECT Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID, SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

I'm trying to rewrite the query using subquery correlation:

```
SELECT Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID,
       (SELECT SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
        GROUP BY SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

I have the following error and I don't understand what I need to fix:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Also it will be good if will suggest different options correlation to the original query. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the group by in the subquery, add a correlation instead:

```
SELECT Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID,
       (SELECT SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
        WHERE Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Same, using table aliases:

```
SELECT soh.CustomerID,
       (SELECT SUM(sod.LineTotal)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
        WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT soh.CustomerID,
       (SELECT SUM(sod.LineTotal)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
        WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
```

Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows, and return the same result as the `GROUP BY` version.

Comment: It turned 31465 rows 19119 instead.

Comment: If interested, you can download the database here. https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/880661

Comment: 31349 rows received.

Comment: I understand, there are Sales.SalesOrderHeader rows without references in the Sales.SalesOrderDetail table. The sub-query version is actually more a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. Do you want those rows or not?

Comment: Yes, they are needed.

Comment: Range variables, not table aliases.

Comment: @onedaywhen, sorry, but I don't get you here. Are you talking about soh and sod?

Comment: That's right, they are range variables (I was impressed with you correcting someone's use of 'CASE statement). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000362/15354.

Comment: @onedaywhen, according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard they are `<correlation name>`'s, but most people don't know what you're talking about if you say that.

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding, sub-query must return only one value for each row. Your code:

```
(SELECT SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
        GROUP BY SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID)
```

will return more then one value because you are grouping by `SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID` and the resultset will have as many rows as different `SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID`are in the table.

So you have to remove group by clause and it will work. Otherwise if you want to have respective value as per `SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID` then you have to use where clause as in **jarlh** answer:

```
(SELECT SUM(SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal)
        FROM SalesOrderDetail
        WHERE SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
```

which will give to result-set a value per row which is filtered with `SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID`.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the situation. Any guesses why the different number of rows received?

Comment: Which statement is giving different number of rows?

Comment: **jarlh** answer - 31465 rows. The original query - 19119.