# How to delete items from a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which returns the items that need to be deleted. What should the query be to delete these items.

```
SELECT p1.ID
FROM pidata_load p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p2.ID FROM pi_base p2 WHERE p1.pbid = p2.ID)
```

Is it safe to do this?

```
DELETE FROM pidata_load
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p2.ID FROM pi_base p2 WHERE pbid = p2.ID)
GO
```

Update 1 - Here is my query with an alias on the outer table

```
DELETE p1 FROM pidata_load AS p1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p2.ID FROM pi_base p2 WHERE p1.pbid = p2.ID)
GO
```

Comment: If your first query is returning the data you want, then yes, your second query will `delete` those rows. You should probably still alias the outer table though...

Comment: Yes and this is a very good practice to verify the where before you perform the delete

Comment: How would I alias the outer table?

Comment: alias the outer table thus: `DELETE pi FROM pidata_load AS pi WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: @sgeddes: I'm not convinced your suggested change is worth the bother but it does highlight the fact that `pi` is not a 'table alias'! Think about it literally: does "Delete table from table where search condition" make sense? No, because `pi` is a range variable and if it is an alias for anything then it would be a row i.e. `pi` 'ranges' over the table and when it satisfies the search condition then the row is deleted.

Comment: @onedaywhen -- In general when using correlated subqueries I'd highly recommend aliasing the outer table.  If the `pbid` field were in both tables, then this query would fail...  Better to be safe in my opinion and explicitly define what you are correlating on.  In regards to your other comment, `p1` is a table alias -- it is an alias to `pidata_load` in the first query.  Just as `p2` is an alias to `pi_base` in the subquery.  Not sure I'm following you there.

Comment: @RossPresser - I took that and changed my query using p1 instead of pi, I think that might have derailed some of the comments.

Comment: @sgeddes: re range variables: Are you a 'learn from a book' person? See citations in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996863/in-sql-what-is-the-letter-after-a-table-name-in-a-select-statement/1000362#1000362). Are you a 'try it myself' person? Try writing some [LINQ to Objects in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693052.aspx), it's an interesting data language ('query syntax' rather than 'lambdas'). If you are a 'toe the industry line' person (nothing wrong with that) then ignore the mathematics, just call it a 'table alias' and don't learn anything new today :)

Comment: @sgeddes: I'm not sure what you mean by 'to be safe' (either something works as intended or not) but we are in agreement on always including alias/range variables e.g. I can never remember which the 'outer' table is supposed to be!

Answer (score 2):

Yes that will work. The DELETE statement works much like the SELECT statement, but it deletes the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `EXISTS` is valid in the `WHERE` clause of a delete statement.

You can use `IN` to check against the Id as well. Pretty sure that this is **less efficient** than `EXISTS`. In my opinion, it is a little bit **easier to read** as well, but again know it is **less efficient**.

```
--With a query
SELECT p1.ID
FROM pidata_load p1
WHERE p1.ID NOT IN (SELECT p2.ID FROM pi_base)

--with regular values or parameters
SELECT p1.ID
FROM pidata_load p1
WHERE p1.ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: First you were "Pretty sure" but by the end you "know". Who needs citations or evidence, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `definitely it safe` to use delete statement instead of select.

It is `good practice` to test delete statement with select prior to execute.