# MySQL aliases affecting performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I'm trying to streamline my sql queries for mysql. The use of aliases makes it much easier for me to read, but does it impact the performance? The fact each alias and it's reference have to be stored  memory and every time it's referred too, the processor will in theory have more to deal with. Is this worth doing?

Comment: The answer is No. See it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363108/how-does-table-alias-names-affect-performance

Comment: What sort of testing did you do on your own?

Comment: Don't do anything like that!!! Don't ruin your code to save 0.0001% performance.