# Viewing A Teradata Alias

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I wrote a query where I misspelled the alias I was using (this is pseudocode)

```
SELECT
    ma.name
    FROM mytable my
```

Teradata SQL Assistant did not give its usual error message saying ***ma*** does not exist, but ran for a long time and spooled out. I believe Teradata was processing all the rows in ***mytable***.

When I changed the column selector to ***my.name*** the query ran as expected.

My question is, is it possible to see what Teradata SQL Assistant thinks the value of ***ma*** is?
Is there some setting which might define the default value of ***ma***?

***ma*** is not a column name in ***mytable***

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353672/teradata-use-of-aliases-impacts-explain-estimation-of-time Try a `SHOW SELECT ...` which returns all objects accessed by a query (but it might fail depending on your access rights).

Comment: @dnoeth +1 Nice answer on the link