# Is there any performance slowdown while using custom table alias instead of direct table name with columns in sql select command?

Tags: sql-server, table-alias

I am working on project with huge data and usage. Many procedures are being used with multiple joined SQL Select queries.

My friend told me that using column names with table name is much better in respect to performance instead using column with table alias.

**Query my friend suggested**

```
select Employee.Name, Employee.Address, District.DistName
From Employee
INNER JOIN District ON Employee.DistCode=District.DistCode
```

**Query I am currently using**

```
select e.Name, e.Address, dist.DistName
From Employee e
INNER JOIN District dist ON e.DistCode=dist.DistCode
```

As far as I know, table aliases boost up query readability. 
Is there also any performance effect with table aliasing vs direct table name.

Comment: No. Everything is resolved at compile time.

Comment: so, is there any extra overhead occur on compiler to resolve actual table from alias?

Comment: Ask your "friend" for proof with an actual demonstration.

Comment: No, there's no actual over-head. If you do want a (very) slight improvement, you should fully schema qualify your table names (like "FROM dbo.Employee e")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does table alias names affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363108/how-does-table-alias-names-affect-performance)

Comment: Interesting comment in that potential duplicate above -  at the lower-voted answer there is a comment suggesting a link made in the question's comments has an answer that suggests a rare issue in SQL Server 2000. Perhaps where this thought originated? (My sister's friend's mother's best friend's said once...)

Comment: Wow I have heard some strange wives tales about performance in sql server but this is a new one.