# What does this mean in sql query

Tags: sql

```
join  Organisation o (NOLOCK) on o.OrganisationID = h.OrganisationId
```

I just want to know, what does the `o` before `nolock` mean? I have also seen people putting `a`, `u` and `h` in front of `nolock` - what is it referring to?

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, I am just a beginner in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

That o is merely an alias of Organization - a nickname, so that you can type less (and query seems to be cleaner). Otherwise you have to state the long name and say:

```
join Organisation (NOLOCK) on Organisation.OrganisationID = h.OrganisationId
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically that `o` is an example of a [`table alias`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) which can optionally be used with `AS` also

```
join  Organisation AS o
```

the `h` also contained in the join condition is also a `table alias`, something like this

```
FROM Hospitals AS h
JOIN Organisation AS o (NOLOCK) on o.OrganisationID = h.OrganisationId
```

In most cases aliases are used to simplify (or shorten) code, and many also view this as making the code more legible. Aliases can on occasion be necessary; for example if using a lookup table more then once in a query the table aliases (L1 & L2 below) becomes essential to differentiate the joined data.

```
FROM MyDataTable AS D
INNER JOIN MyLookupTable AS L1 D.code1 = L1.lookup_code
INNER JOIN MyLookupTable AS L2 D.code2 = L2.lookup_code
```

Attitudes regarding use of aliases differ markedly from strong proponents to strong detractors. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043/sql-table-aliases-good-or-bad) as an example.